# Error when sending document to configured records centre

Tags: content-organizer, records-center, send-to-destination

I have a document library as the source and a records library as the target.

The send to connection has been configured to the target using [these steps](http://www.boostsolutions.com/blog/how-to-configure-send-to-connections-in-sharepoint-2010/).

However, I never reach step 6. I instead receive an error which says the records library **could not be found or accessed**.

I have the Content Organizer Feature activated on both source and target sites.
I have the server application pool account as a member of the Records Center Web Service Submitters on the target site.
I have the correct URL in the Central Admin configure send to connections field.

Can anyone suggest any other reasons why this error is happening? I'm so stuck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out on my own because I'm a G. Details below:

I deactivated and then re-enabled the Content Organizer feature on the target records centre.

This created a new permission group, called "Records Center Web Service Submitters for (1)". I added the necessary App Pool account into this permission group and tested. This fixed the problem.

Even though I had added the app pool account into the first "Records Center Web Service Submitters" permission group, Sharepoint wasn't playing ball. It is now, I've tamed this wild harlot.