# NotFound coming back from SubmitFile

Tags: rest, 2016, sharepoint-rest-api, records-center

Hi I've got a hightrust application on sharepoint 2016. On development the submitfile worked although the website and the sharepoint site were both on the same server.

Moving to staging and the sharepoint site is on one site and the IIS website on another.

When I call submitfile I get the reply `<ResultCode>NotFound</ResultCode>`

I've checked and the appPool which the soap request is running as does have access as well as being in the `"Records Center Web Service Submitters"` group.

I've tested using soapui the '`GetServerInfo`' and it does seem to have access as it gets results back.

There are a few errors floating around the ULS logs

```
EntityTypes calculated. Web: 'ff2dee5d-b283-4413-b16a-2c4e27a53acf', WebApp: 'null', EntityTypeCount: '5'.
EntityTypes calculated. Web: 'ff2dee5d-b283-4413-b16a-2c4e27a53acf', WebApp: 'null', EntityTypeCount: '1'.

SPSecurityTokenServiceManager!EnsureSharePointLogonRequestClaims: InputIdentity doesn't conatin a PrimarySid claim.

SPLoggingLock held lock for 469 milliseconds. Call stack:   
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPLoggingLockTag.Dispose()    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPPersistedObjectCollectionCache.InvalidateCache

SPMicrofeedContext.SetMySiteHostForContext failed System.UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The URI is empty.
```

But in all honesty I'm not too sure they have anything todo with it.

Any ideas?

**Additional Info**
I'm using the sharepoint soap request library ie.

```
  var listsProxy = new CESARecordSubmit.RecordsRepositorySoapClient();
                    listsProxy.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
                    listsProxy.Endpoint.Address = endpoint;
                    listsProxy.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;
```

Part with properties etc.

```
 var result = listsProxy.SubmitFile(bytesArray, records.ToArray(), "xxxxx", _spAppPool.Site.RootWeb.Url + file.ServerRelativeUrl, _sp.LoginName);
```

The appPool user of the IIS site is in the "Records Center Web Service Submitters" group.

Comment: This could use some additional information. Is the application on SharePoint trying to call a web service on the external IIS site, or is an IIS hosted application trying to call a SharePoint built-in service?  What url is being hit when the NotFound error is received, what method (POST, GET, etc.) is the call?

Comment: I've added a bit of the code there to show you what I'm doing.

Comment: @willman any ideas?

Comment: Also one other question is the NotFound in reference to the user in '_sp.LoginName' or the user who is running the soap command?

Comment: A NotFound resultcode usually means the URL endpoint could not be found.  Are you sure that the value of your `endpoint` is reachable from the IIS machine?

Comment: or potentially the `_spAppPool` value?

Comment: Reasonably sure there are other API's around and they seem ok.
My collegue meantioned the _spAppPool value - I'll be checking it today.

Comment: I checked all those values and still ok. Also had it been that I would have thought I would have got the same errors on my development box.

Comment: Well you mentioned that it works when the app is on the same box as SharePoint, so that's why the most likely cause is a URL that only works locally, like `http:\\localhost`, or a Windows firewall blocking incoming calls.

Answer (score 0):

Worked this one out, half my own fault but it's a situation that anyone can find themselves in. We had some trouble with the records centre as we were doing some importing in and wanted to reset to try again.

So basically deleted the records centre and recreated. 
SP in it's wisdom decided to give me a new `Records Center Web Service Submitters` group named `Records Center Web Service Submitters (1)`

Not thinking it required I deleted it and put my users in the other one.

Clearly SP ties the group (somehow) to it's submit file process and has just chosen to negate the other one.

If you want to bring back the other one then 
"I deactivated and then re-enabled the Content Organizer feature on the target records centre."

Citing the question/answer here.
[Error when sending document to configured records centre](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/156932/error-when-sending-document-to-configured-records-centre)